# Unzipping the openfda data in R

Tags: openfda, programming, json

I've downloaded all the url's for the different drug-event pairs, but they all end in .zip.
Does anyone know how to automate pulling the .json file out of these zip files without doing it manually for each one? I'm not sure how to unzip the files.

```
library(jsonlite)
# create a character vector of all 961 available download files
url <- "https://api.fda.gov/download.json"
document <- fromJSON(url)
results <- document$results
drug_event <- results$drug$event
files <- as.character(drug_event$partitions$file)

# unzipping the files
file1 <- files[1]
temp <- tempfile()
download.file(file1,temp)
unz(temp, "data.json")
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use  [`for`](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Repetitive-execution):

```
# unzipping the files
temp<-tempfile()
for (f in files) {
    download.file(f,temp)
    unzip(temp)
}
```